# Action Bar Buttons position

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put a button in the action bar instead of the application icon which means at left. I have tried orderInCategory but it doesn't help.
What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the icon of the "home" section of the `Action Bar`, you can use `ActionBar.setIcon()` programatically, or set `android:icon` in your XML. If you want to do something more complex than that (have multiple buttons, or be able to customize them further), you need to set a custom view in your action bar.

To set a custom view in your action bar, you need to do the following:

Create a layout for your custom view:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:width="wrap_content"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then inflate it and set it as your action bar's custom view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
ImageView button = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(...);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
```

Hope that helps